# Two-dimensional associative array such as p["A"][[n]]

Tags: associations

I am trying to use Associations in order to clean up / factorize my code but am still confused about how these work. In the code below, I have an object p which is 2-dimensional (or rather I am hoping this is what I did). On one dimension, the type ("A" or "B", which is a string) and the other an index (which is an integer). I added the line with Table in order to "declare" initial values for p but this does not seem to do the trick...

```
ClearAll[p]
Table[p[type] = ConstantArray[0, 2], {type, {"A", "B"}}];
p["A"][[1]] = 1;
p["A"][[2]] = 2;
p["B"][[1]] = 3;
p["B"][[2]] = 4;
p["A"] (* expected output: {1,2}, but I these messages: "p[A] in the part assignment is not a symbol." *)
```

Basically, I have a paremeter p for each of a number of types of calculations. For each p["type"], if you will, I want to be able to access elements of a vector but also the whole vector as well. Is there a modification in the above, or some other way altogether, to achieve this?

Comment: Your code does not use associative arrays as written.  Did you forget to add the part `p = <||>` after the `Clear[p]`?

Comment: Have you tried starting with something like: `assc = <|"A" -> {1, 2}, "B" -> {3, 4}|>`?

Comment: @JasonB. you are likely correct and it is possible that though I thought what I did was an associative array it is not. The comment below seems to concur?

Comment: @MarcoB no I had not, and that seems to work except that I am unsure how to set those without hardcoding A and B?

Comment: @sg1234 I am not sure that I follow. Once you have `assc`, then you can add more entries to it, either by hand or programmatically. For instance, once `assc` has been defined, you could say `assc["C"] = {89, 89}` and that would add an entry for `"C"`.

Comment: @MarcoB I understand what you are saying now I think : had I started with an initial association, as proposed by Jason B. in their answer (which I have accepted) which uses an empty association, then I could have used Table or Do to fill in the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(* create an empty association *)
ClearAll[p];
p = <||>;
(* then populate the keys with empty lists *)
Do[p[type] = ConstantArray[0, 2], {type, {"A", "B"}}];

(* now use Part syntax to set the values *)
p[["A", 1]] = 1;
p[["A", 2]] = 2;
p[["B", 1]] = 3;
p[["B", 2]] = 4;

(* returns as expected *)
p["A"]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks! Is there an intuitive way to understand why, in this case, initializing the association (using Do[]) seems to be mandatory? Are there any links you would suggest for me to familiarize myself with the various types of "array" shapes that exist in Mathematica? Thanks again!